# detect new service with bonjour sdk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sdk, mfc, bonjour

i have sucesfully implement the bonjour sdk in visual c++ dialog application. the application brows all services and show them in the "Tree", but I want to know if there is a method in bonjour sdk to detect if new service was added and then refresh the content.
thx

Comment: Do you mean the Bonjour SDK supplied by Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Bonjour SDK supplied by Apple availible for Windows this is actually taken care of automatically.

Look closely at the method for browsing services: [DNSServiceBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/DNSServiceBrowse). It has a callback parameter that will get called when there is a new service found. Just make sure to call [DNSProcessResults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/DNSServiceProcessResult) when needed. You can either block in this call, or use Poll/Select to detect when the file desciptor has data to read.